# Mostrar datos en un arreglo json

Tags: php

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, tengo una consulta por un arreglo json, el cual me funciona bien al mostrar todos los datos ya grabados con anterioridad, pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es que cuando uno ingrese la marca del vehículo ya ingresado, debe mostrar los datos, este es el código que estoy usando:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"){
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    require("conexion1.php");
    $conexion = retornarConexion();
    $Marca = $_GET ['Marca_Vehiculo'];
    $query="SELECT N_Filas,Tipo_Vehiculo,Marca_Vehiculo,Modelo_Vehiculo,Activo FROM vehiculo1 WHERE Marca_Vehiculo = $Marca and Activo = 1 
    Order By N_Filas asc";
    $resultado=$conexion->query($query);
    if($conexion->affected_rows>0){
        $json="{\"data\":[";
        while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            $json=$json.json_encode($row);
            $json=$json.",";
        }
        $json=substr(trim($json),0,-1);
        $json=$json."]}";
    }
    echo $json;
    $resultado->close();
    $conexion->close();
}
?>
```

ahora en la línea del select es donde me da el error, no sé si me falta algún discriminador o un delimitador, favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: se me olvido mencionar que la idea en si es poder mostrarlo en un table layout para android studio

Comment: No especificas el motor de base de datos. Las cadenas en SQL van entrecomilladas, intenta con `Marca_Vehiculo = '$Marca'`.

Comment: @Sal muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me salvaste el día por completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien indica @sal, debes usar comillas para valores de tipo cadena en consultas SQL.

Ahora bien, el tema de la seguridad es importante, pasar una consulta como la tuya directamente abriría la puerta a ataques de *inyección SQL*, lo cual supone un gravísimo problema de seguridad. Para evitarlo, lo mejor es usar consultas preparadas.

Por otro lado, no deberías usar `affected_rows` para consultas del tipo `SELECT`, esa propiedad es para consultas del tipo `DELETE`, `INSERT` o `UPDATE`. Es importante que leas la documentación antes de empezar a trabajar con una herramienta, más aún si se trata del manejo de datos.

Dado que quieres obtener un JSON como respuesta final, podrías usar el método `fetch_object()`, que te ayudará a escribir el código de forma más simple y natural sin tener que recurrir a trucos hechos a mano como esto `$json=substr(trim($json),0,-1);` o esto `$json=$json."]}";` Pero mysqli en algunas versiones depende de otro controlador que no viene instalado en todos los entornos PHP para funcionar sin demasiadas complicaciones. Por eso no usaremos `fetch_object()`, pero sí trabajaremos convirtiendo el array de filas con `json_decode(json_encode($rows))`.

Por último, no programes de forma ingenua. Verifica todo aquello que podría ser nulo o vacío antes de proceder. Sólo así tendrás un código maduro, que debe contemplar el manejo de errores.

Corrigiendo todo lo dicho, podrías escribir tu código así:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"){
    $Marca = $_GET ['Marca_Vehiculo'] ?? NULL;
    if ($Marca) {
        require("conexion1.php");
        $conexion = retornarConexion();
        if ($conexion) {
            $query="SELECT N_Filas,Tipo_Vehiculo,Marca_Vehiculo,Modelo_Vehiculo,Activo FROM vehiculo1 WHERE Marca_Vehiculo = ? and Activo = 1 
    Order By N_Filas asc";
            if ($stmt=$conexion->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $Marca);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($Filas, $Tipo, $MarcaV, $Modelo, $Activo);
                $rows=array();
                while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
                    $rows[]=array('N_Filas'=>$Filas,'Tipo_Vehiculo'=>$Tipo,'Marca_Vehiculo'=>$MarcaV,'Modelo_Vehiculo'=>$Modelo,'Activo'=>$Activo);
                }
                $stmt->close();
                if ($rows) {
                    $data=array('data'=>json_decode(json_encode($rows)));
                } else {
                    $data=array('error'=>'No filas encontradas');
                }
            } else {
                $data=array('error'=>'Error en consulta SQL');
            }
            $conexion->close();
        } else {
            $data=array('error'=>'No hay conexión');
        }
    } else {
        $data=array('error'=>'No se postearon datos');
    }
} else {
    $data=array('error'=>'Método no permitido');
}
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario y ayuda, estuve probado el nuevo código y me arrojo este problema: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\oficina\buscar_vehiculos3.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\oficina\buscar_vehiculos3.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />, y la línea 16 es la siguiente: while($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc()){, puede ser de conexión pero funciona bien, además te comento que utilizo el visual studio code y desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: @Hector sí disculpa, cometí un error ahí, cambia lo que hay en la línea 16, donde está el `while` por esto: **`while($row=$stmt->fetch()){`**

Comment: master te agradezco, le hice una prueba de vuelta y funciona como siempre, te agradezco nuevamente tu ayuda y comprensión.

Comment: @Hector me alegro de que haya funcionado. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta correcta te la dio el usuario SAL.

Yo lo único que agrego es que seria bueno que filtraras la variable $MARCA para evitar ataques de código SQL. Algo así:

```
$Marca = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_GET['Marca_Vehiculo']);
```

Saludos